# C# - Assigning an empty dropdown list to a full one does not work

Tags: c#, webforms, drop-down-menu

I have two DropDownLists on my form. There's no item in neither one. In my Page_Load event I assign them to DropDownList objects returned from private methods. But when the page loads both dropdownlists are still empty. I debugged inside the methods that return the filled dropdown lists, they contain items. Is there any problem with doing so?

The Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ddlUserTypes = UserTypesList();
    }
}

   private DropDownList UserTypesList()
{
    DropDownList ddList = new DropDownList();
    StaticDataProvider stDataProv = new StaticDataProvider();
    ddList.DataSource = stDataProv.UserTypes();
    ddList.DataTextField = "Value";
    ddList.DataValueField = "Key";
    ddList.DataBind();

    return ddList;
}
```

Also when I Response.Write() the items of the ddlUserTypes I get all the items listed on my page. It seems the items are there, they're just not visible.

Comment: Can we see your code? Web Forms or MVC ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        UserTypesList(ddlUserTypes);
    }


private void UserTypesList(DropDownList ddList)
{
    StaticDataProvider stDataProv = new StaticDataProvider();
    ddList.DataSource = stDataProv.UserTypes();
    ddList.DataTextField = "Value";
    ddList.DataValueField = "Key";
    ddList.DataBind();
}
```

You create a new instance of a control and simply assign in place to the current one from the page. When you create a new control you have to use `Controls.Add`, which probably does and other things behind the scenes.

Comment: Hmmm, nice spot. Thank you and all very much

Answer (score 4):

Fix for the code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        UserTypesList(ddlUserTypes);
    }
}

   private void UserTypesList(DropDownList ddList)
{

    StaticDataProvider stDataProv = new StaticDataProvider();
    ddList.DataSource = stDataProv.UserTypes();
    ddList.DataTextField = "Value";
    ddList.DataValueField = "Key";
    ddList.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: Who are you to assume his problem? He doesn't say how he adds the items. I don't understand the downvote.

Comment: OP edited the question and this is not the problem. Sometimes we need to wait and not jump with an answer..

Answer (score 0):

Can we see your code? Web Forms or MVC ?

Have you tried setting the DataValueField and the DataTextField properties of the drop down list also are you calling the .DataBind() of the dropdown?

Really need to see your code in order to provide an answer..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guess, without seeing any code. Try doing it in the prerender event handler instead of the load handler.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
DropDownLists.Items.Refresh
```